# How to use Jupyter Notebook in RHEL5 Cloud Machine

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using RHEL5 cloud desktop (via putty). This doesn't have any UI or Browser.

Prereq: I have installed anaconda3. so Jupyter comes included. I am able to launch jupyter notebook. however, i am getting this warning

> "No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser."

How to launch jupyter-notebook in cloud machine and access it from my local pc.

Answer (score 0):

I followed below approach and was able to configure jupyter in remote server.

https://agent-jay.github.io/2018/03/jupyterserver/#step-3-running-a-public-notebook-server-via-the-web

Step 1: Password Setup

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
$ jupyter notebook password
Enter password:  ****
Verify password: ****
```

[NotebookPasswordApp] Wrote hashed password to /Users/you/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json

Note: Use this hashed password when editing jupyter_notebook_config.json in step 3

Step 2: Using SSL for Encrypted Communication

```
$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

Note: The above command is slightly different from the one in official Jupyter docs, which didn’t work for me for some reason.

Step 3: Running a Public notebook server (via the web)

Open /Users/you/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py with your favourite text editor and edit the following

Set options for certfile, ip, password, toggle off and browser auto-opening

```
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/absolute/path/to/your/certificate/mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = u'/absolute/path/to/your/certificate/mycert.pem'
# Set ip to '*' to your IP address.
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:bcd259ccf...<your hashed password here>'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
# It is a good idea to set a known, fixed port for server access
c.NotebookApp.port = 9999
```

Step 4: Run Jupyter Lab/Notebook

```
$ jupyter notebook
```